# How to get the listing of available subtitles for a particular video from youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am embedding youtube video into iframe, is there anyway so that i get the lisitng of available subtitles and show it in the drop down menu. If user select any particular language i just change the src attribute of iframe so that the video play with that subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [`Captions: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) which returns a list of caption tracks that are associated with a specified video. Note that the API response does not contain the actual captions and that the [`captions.download`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) method provides the ability to retrieve a caption track.  Set the [`videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#videoId) parameter value to the YouTube video ID that uniquely identifies the video for which you are retrieving captions.

Your request must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).

Scopes

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`

Example. The request below retrieves a list of captions for a video on the Google Stories YouTube channel:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.captions.list?
part=snippet
&videoId=PRU2ShMzQRg
```

Hope this helps!